# Why is the Nginx development version installed on Ubuntu 12.04 and not the stable version?

Tags: 12.04, nginx

I have Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with **nginx 1.1.19**. According to nginx documentation, release 1.1.19 is a development release. Why does the 12.04 repository have this development release rather than a stable release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution anyway, since I found nginx 1.19 segfaults with try files. I removed it and installed the stable version.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove nginx
```

Then:

```
nginx=stable 
echo "deb ppa.launchpad.net/nginx$nginx/ubuntu lucid main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-$nginx-lucid.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C300EE8C
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

- [Patch](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/changeset/4601/nginx)
- [Source](http://awesomism.co.uk/242093)